# JPA @ManyToOne relation: Do not insert new entities?

Tags: java, jpa

I am using JPA to model and persist my entities.
I have several "reference" entities which simply exist on the database and are used in many entities with @ManyToOne relations. These reference entities should only be queried, not updated or inserted.

For example, my *ReferenceCurrency* entity contains values for ("EUR", "Euro") and ("USD", "US Dollar"). I do not want to get new currencies in my system because someone made a typo like "USF").

Example entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CURRENCY")
public class ReferenceCurrency implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 3)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "DSC")
    private String description;

    /* hashCode() + equals() */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY")
public class EntityA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 3)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "CURRENCY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ReferenceCurrency currency;

    /* hashCode() + equals() */
}
```

**Question**

*What would be the best way to only allow existing values in Entity.currency fields, and not insert new values if the currency does not exist?
AFAIK this cannot be solved simply with annotations (bean validation or JPA annotations).

Must I resolve to a @PrePersist / @PreConstruct method which checks the existence of the ReferenceCurrency entity? Is there a more elegant way?*

Comment: Why not [populate the currencies in-application](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCurrencies) instead of storing/reading from the database?

Comment: Where does ReferenceCurrency objects come from? Can you make this Entity read only?

Comment: The application has multiple layers, this Java app Ine of them. Populating the currencies in the Java layer results in double registration of the currencies which we do not want. How could I make the ReferenceCurrency readonly?